# How to use "page tour tooltip" as mouse hover tooltip too

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I've used [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/) jquery page tour at my webpage. So, at first tooltips come at every section each by one. I want, after ending tutorial, if the user put mouse on that section, that tooltip will come again. Like, at my webpage, the structure of HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="tour_1 tooltip-text">?</div>
    <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="tour_2 tooltip-text">?</div>
    <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

tooltip identify each div by `.tour_1`, `.tour_2` etc. So, tooltip comes for `.tour_1` at first, then `.tour_2` ... I want, if user hover on the `.tour_1`, tooltip will come too for `.tour_1`. if user hover on the `.tour_2`, tooltip will come too for `.tour_2`. How can I make this? In short, I want something like that:

```
.tour_1.hover(function() {
  .tour_1.showTooltip()
});
.tour_2.hover(function() {
  .tour_2.showTooltip()
});
```

[My Fiddle Work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/2Kj37/1/)

Comment: Where are your tooltip texts located? Inline, where you now have question marks? If so, I created a native/vanilla Javascript tooltip with inline texts, that appear on mouseover (and on onclick on touchscreens). I don't know if it can be easily combined with the page tour script, but if you're interested let me know and I'll post the code and a demo.

Comment: Every tooltip is located on it's own section, like first tooltip located on div.tour_1, 2nd tooltip on div.tour_2 etc(but, at fiddle, it can't show properly. It seem all the tooltip is located in same position. I don't know the reason. But, it works at my webpage, just not working the position at the fiddle). I ain't so good at jQuery. So, maybe, I can't able to implement your tooltip into the page tour script :(

Comment: I missed your Fiddle when I wrote my first comment, and I now see that all your tooltip texts are located in the script. That would make it very difficult to integrate with my method. I hope someone else will be able to help you. Good luck.